# How do I get Azure credentials using "@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth" in node.js?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

```
const msRestNodeAuth = require("@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {   
    let credentials = await msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, clientSecret, tenant);
    console.log('credentials==> ',credentials);

    context.res = {
        body: credentials
    };
}
```

While generating the credentials then getting the error.
"**Exception has occurred: Error: Entry not found in cache.**".

**Why I'm getting the above error ??**

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to offical document first.

**[Manage Azure websites with Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-web-nodejs-manage/app-service-web-nodejs-manage/)**

I have test it, and it works for me. I use `npm i @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth` and `npm i azure-arm-resource` to run my test code.

```
const msRestNodeAuth = require("@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth");
const resourceManagement = require("azure-arm-resource");

var clientId = "3b417***f7928ad";;
var domain = "72f9****1db47";
var secret = "RnX****7X1T";
var subscriptionId = 'b83***4c23f';
var resourceClient;

msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(clientId, secret, domain, function (err, credentials) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  resourceClient =new resourceManagement.ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);
  console.log('apiVersion==> ',resourceClient.apiVersion);
})
```

[image]